# Search a word from description and return the description starting from that word

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any function to search a word from a description and return the description with starting from that word or just the word before that searching word?.

if this is the description..

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s.

I want to search a word 'printing'. And the result must be show like this..

> printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
>   standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

OR

> the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
>   industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

the result will show from the word that i am searching or just one word before the searching word.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the MySQL builtin functions here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(description FROM LOCATE('printing', description))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the description first. Probably the best way to get it is an query:

```
SELECT description FROM table WHERE description LIKE %printing%
```

Then you can do some string voodoo with RegEx to obtain the part of the description you look for.